# PostgreSQL LIKE operator doesn't match hyphen

Tags: postgresql, escaping, sql-like

I've a problem with LIKE operator in PostgreSQL. It does not match patterns that contain the `-` character. I've tried to escape these characters using the ESCAPE option, but it still does not work.

Query:

```
select * from footable where trascrizione like '% [---]is Abraam %';
```

Sample data (contents of column `trascrizione`):

```
[---]is Abraam [e]t Ise[---] / ((crux quadrata))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show us your query and some data you expect to match.

Comment: this is a semplified example of my query:  
  
`select * from footable where trascrizione like '% [---]is Abraam %';`

it returns a void result set (but I know that there's one record that matchs).

Comment: And what is the row you expected to match?

Comment: The row that has this value for the field trascrizione:  
"[---]is Abraam [e]t Ise[---] / ((crux quadrata))"

Comment: @Antonio F.: Your duty is to clarify your question by editing it, not by making it clear in the comments. The question should be answerable by just reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pattern would not match because there is no space before `[---]is Ambraam`.  There is a space in your pattern, between the `%` and `[` characters, and it's requiring that space to be in your data.  Try `LIKE '%[---]is Abraam %'`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was not the abscence of whitespace between '[' and '-', but a whitespace before the '%' and '['. I have to trim the string.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code. I have no problem:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a LIKE '%-' AND b LIKE '%-%' AND c LIKE '-%';
  a   | b |  c   | d | e 
------+---+------+---+---
 foo- | - | -bar |   | 
(1 Zeile)
```